# Automating DLL Debugging "attach to process" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I'm writing an SNMP extension agent DLL for Windows.

Is there a way to automatically attach the DLL to the SNMP service each time I want to test/debug?

This is a very tedious and time consuming process, as I currently have to stop the SNMP service, compile, restart the service and then attach the process. I'm trying to automate it more.

Comment: You could stop and restart the service in pre and post build events, use the NET command.  __debugbreak() to trigger a break and invoke the jit debugger probably doesn't work in a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may be what you want to have a look at.

Visual Studio debugger offers some command line option to attach to running process. You can probably write a Python script to enumerate running processes and attach the debugger to the service. I think you need admin priviledge to do that.

.Net has a convinient Debugger.Launch(), but I can't find an equivalent for the native.